# Error in export sqoop command

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I was using the export command in `sqoop` and facing this error while exporting from `hdfs` to `MySQL`
The command is:

```
sqoop export 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/property 
--username root 
--password root 
--table xyz 
--m 1 
--export-dir abc.csv
```

The error is:

```
16/08/30 23:11:33 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/30 23:11:34 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/08/30 23:11:34 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/08/30 23:11:34 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:848)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:736)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:759)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1773)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1578)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `mysql-connector.jar` in `$SQOOP_HOME/lib`.

As per Sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server),

> You can use Sqoop with any other JDBC-compliant database. First, download the appropriate JDBC driver for the type of database you want to import, and install the `.jar` file in the `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` directory on your client machine

Also,

> Each driver `.jar` file also has a specific driver class which defines the entry-point to the driver. For example, MySQL’s Connector/J library has a driver class of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Refer to your database vendor-specific documentation to determine the main driver class. This class must be provided as an argument to Sqoop with `--driver`.

So, add `--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in your command.